# moreコマンドの仕様について

Tags: linux, centos

moreコマンドの仕様は、どこで確認出来るでしょうか？

---

**試したこと**
・CentOS7

```
man more
```

> more は、 3.0BSD に登場した。 この man ページは 現在 Linux コミュニティで利用されている more バージョン
>        5.19 (Berkeley 6/29/88)について書かれている。

---

**Q1.3.0BSDについて**
・ここで記載されているBSDは、ライセンスではなくOSの意味ですか？
・「CentOS」と「BSD」の関係性が分かりません
・「BSD」内容を「CentOS」でも利用しているのでしょうか？

---

**Q2. Linux コミュニティで利用されている more バージョン 5.19 (Berkeley 6/29/88)**
・more バージョン 5.19に関する情報はどこに掲載されているのでしょうか？
・この場合のLinux コミュニティは何を指すのでしょうか？
・Berkeleyは相性？
・6/29/88は日付？？

Comment: 「仕様」とおっしゃいますが具体的にどの様な情報を求めているのかがはっきりしません。コマンドとしての振る舞いは既に試された`man more`に記載されています。CentOSもといLinuxを構成するコマンドの多くは他のUNIX系OSを参考にしたり移植されており、BSDもその中の１つです。Windowsにもmoreコマンドがありますが、こちらはLinuxのそれとは振る舞いが違います。同じLinuxでも例えばDebianとCentOSではmoreの仕様が異なるかも知れないと思われている？

Comment: 参考までに、more.c 5.19 (Berkeley) 6/29/88 のソースコードは[こちら](http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/43BSDTahoe/ucb/more/more.c?rev=1.1.1.1)です。なお、6/29/88 は日付で1988年6月29日になります("mm/dd/yy"形式)。

Comment: 参考: POSIX コマンドとしての `more` の説明は [IEEE Std 1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/more.html) にあります。

Comment: @cubick。CentOSのコマンドについて調べています。最初はCentOSが仕様を決定していてその内容がPOSIXに記載されている、と思っていたのですが、ディストリビューションなので仕様は別で定義されていて単に取り込んでいるだけなのかなと思い直し、確認している最中です。今回は、manに掲載されている内容以上のことが仕様として定義されているかもしれない、と思い質問しました

Comment: @metropolis。リンクありがとうございます。こういう形で掲載されているのですね。ちなみに、「Revision 1.1.1.1」と「バージョン 5.19」なので比較しづらいのですが、more.c 5.19 (Berkeley) 6/29/88 の意味は、CentOS7では1988年のコードを使用しているということ？ それとも、移植元になったコードが1988年のコードという意味でしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu。 POSIX コマンドmoreとの違いも良くわからないのですが、CentOS7でPOSIX コマンドmoreがデフォルトとして採用されていないのはなぜでしょうか？　POSIXは標準というイメージがあるのですが…。別で質問した方が良いですか？

Comment: @re9 そうですね、別で質問して頂いた方が良さそうです。コメントにするには長いので :)

Comment: CentOSはRHELに追従するポリシーですから、仕様を決定しているのはRHEL、もしくは、その派生元であるFedoraプロジェクトと言えると思います。`more`が標準ではない理由は、より高機能な`less`があるからだと思います。POSIXに準拠させるために`more`も用意されているという感じではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BSD](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD)は

> Berkeley Software Distribution の略語で、1977年から1995年までカリフォルニア大学バークレー校 (University of California, Berkeley, UCB) の Computer Systems Research Group (CSRG) が開発・配布したソフトウェア群、およびUNIXオペレーティングシステム (OS)。

です。ですのでBerkeleyはカリフォルニア大学バークレー校を指します。その上で3BSDは[BSD VAX版](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD#VAX%E7%89%88)より

> 32Vのカーネルをバークレーの学生達が大幅に書きかえて仮想記憶を実装し、2BSDのユーティリティ群をVAXに移植したものと32V由来のユーティリティ群をまとめて完全なOSとしたものが **3BSD** として1979年末にリリースされた。

のことかと。もちろんLinuxとは無関係です。また[4.3BSD](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD#4.3BSD)より

> 4.3BSDリリース後、BSDのプラットフォームを古くなったVAXから新たなプラットフォームへ移行することが決まった。当初 Computer Consoles Inc. の68kベースの Power 6/32（コード名 "Tahoe"）が候補となったが、間もなく開発者らがそれをやめた。それでも **4.3BSD-Tahoe** という移植版（1988年6月）は貴重であり、BSDにおける機種依存コードと機種共通コードの分離をもたらし、将来の移植性向上に寄与した。

ですので、これが[util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux)に[移植](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A7%BB%E6%A4%8D_(%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2))されたことを指すかと。